# O365 autohosted app passing parameters to iframe or alternatives

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, iframe

We have autohosted app web-part for Office online (based of course on Sharpeoint 2013)
Ours app is display list of products from database and by clicking on product display information about product, those pages works on the sharepoint page with inserted App Part, so internal pages are works in the iframe. On the products info page we need to send email notifications with direct link to exact products details page. But we can't pass that Id into App Part. How it is possible to implement?